# List users in local Administrators group using Get-WMIObject

Tags: powershell

I want to fetch the list of users that are present in local `Administrators` group by using `Get-WMIObject`.

I fetched the group name using below command :

```
get-wmiobject win32_group -Filter "Name='Administrators'"
```

Answer (score 3):

I have a function that I use for this task:

```
function Get-LocalAdministrators {  
    param ($strcomputer)  

    $admins = Get-WmiObject win32_groupuser –computer $strcomputer   
    $admins = $admins |? {$_.groupcomponent –like '*"Administrators"'}  

    $admins | ForEach-Object {  
    $_.partcomponent –match ".+Domain\=(.+)\,Name\=(.+)$" > $nul  
    $matches[1].trim('"') + "\" + $matches[2].trim('"')  
    }  
}
```

Usage:

```
Get-LocalAdministrators computer01
```

And to run against the local computer:

```
Get-LocalAdministrators localhost
```